# Flow control based on generic T type

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

Can I ask somebody to explain is it possible to control function flow base on `T` type.
Here is what i'm talking about in `pseudo` typescript code:

```
functionName<T>() { 
 if (T extends Array) { 
   ...
 } else {
   ...
 }
}
```

What i have already found:

```js
type TypeName = T extends any[] ? 'array' : 'object';
```

But the problem i stacked with is that i don't know how to use this `TypeName` further.

Thanks for any activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please treat `T` as an argument. TO be able to use `T` in your conditional type, please add `T` as an argument to your utility type:

```js
type TypeName<T> = T extends any[] ? 'array' : 'object';

type Test1 = TypeName<[]> // 'array'
type Test2 = TypeName<1> // 'object'
```

If you wan to use you function, you can use it in this way:

```js
function check<T>(arg: T) {
  if (Array.isArray(arg)) {
    return 'array'
  } else {
    return 'object'
  }
}
```

Please keep in mind, you can't do smth like that:

```js
function check<T>(arg: T): TypeName<T> {
  if (Array.isArray(arg)) {
    return 'array' // error
  } else {
    return 'object' // error
  }
}
```

You can't use conditional types as a Return Types

I believe that you want to achieve smth like that:

```js
function check<T extends any[]>(arg: T): 'array'
function check<T>(arg: T): 'object'
function check<T>(arg: T) {
  if (Array.isArray(arg)) {
    return 'array' 
  } else {
    return 'object'
  }
}

check([]) // array
check(1) // object
```

More about overloads, you can find [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)

[Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but truth be told i wanna achieve smth like this:
User gives a type and the function creates an object of this type, but implementation differs depend on `T`. If `T` is object, then .... else if `T` is a kind of `T[]` then ..... Is it possible?

Comment: @Ignatella please provide more examples what you want to achieve

Comment: You can't do smth like that: `T extends Array` because `T` is a type, not a value